# Не видет xpath после 10 элемента

Tags: python, парсер, requests, lxml, динамические-структуры

Парсил я значит 100 монет с сайта coinmarketcap.com/ru/ хочу сделать через request потому что так удобнее и быстрее нежели через selenium. Сохраняю я сайт в файл и через etree пытаюсь находить то что мне нужно через xpath все работало пока я не дошел до 11 элемента (tr)

/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div/a/div/div/p - работает
/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[3]/div/a/div/div/p - не работает

Вот код

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import etree
import codecs
url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/ru/?page=1'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

full_page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
html = full_page.text
with codecs.open('coinmarketcap_html.txt', 'w','utf-8') as f:
    f.write(html)
local = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/ru/?page=1'
response = urlopen(local)
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)
print(tree.xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[3]/div/a/div/div/p')[0].text)
```

Какая может быть причина? И можно ли её вообще исправить, или без selenium ни как не обойтись ?

Comment: Может там по 10 шт на странице?

Comment: Там минимум можно поставить 20, если я не ошибаюсь. А даже если и так, тогда на второй странице первый элемент должен быть 11-ый элемент если бы он находился на первой странице